# WebSPhere MQ IBM

Tags: ibm-mq

how do i create application for connect to WebSPhere MQ while WebSPhere installed on another other windows server 2012 and i am creating .net application using c#.net and visualStudio 2013. I am get this error:

```
Exception caught: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'amqmdnet, Version=7.5.0.1, Culture=neutral, publicKeyToken=dd3cb1c9aae9ec97' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. File name: 'amqmdnet, Version=7.5.0.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=dd3cb1c9aae9ec97'.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At IBM MQ v7.5 you need to have a full MQ 7.5 client install on your machine.  The error indicates that you have attempted to copy the `amqmdnet.dll` without a full install. If this is correct there are a few options, two of them are:

1. Install a full IBM MQ 7.5 client install.

   - I would go with the latest 7.5.0.8
   - Keep in mind that 7.5 goes out of support April 30th 2018.
2. MQ v8 and v9 now have a redistributable client install that is a zip file which allows you to have only the `amqmdnet.dll` on your machine if you run your app in Managed .NET client mode.

   - v8 should go out of support at the earliest in June 2019.
   - v9 should go out of support at the earliest in June 2021.